# sitename.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500- Laravel deploy

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment

I am first time deploying my laravel project in a shared hosting.

I got error:

```
This page isn’t working. jsquarehospital.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I deployed following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4

Deploy Method: uploaded project zip in root directory, then uploaded the public folder in **public_html** and changes **index.php**

Please help me. My error log

```
[Sun Oct 18 14:00:33.054366 2020] [php7:warn] [pid 24621] [client 103.25.250.225:28241] PHP Warning:  require(/home/jsquare/domains/jsquarehospital.com/public_html/../jshpanel/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jsquare/domains/jsquarehospital.com/public_html/index.php on line 24
[Sun Oct 18 14:00:33.054390 2020] [php7:error] [pid 24621] [client 103.25.250.225:28241] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/jsquare/domains/jsquarehospital.com/public_html/../jshpanel/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php73/lib/php') in /home/jsquare/domains/jsquarehospital.com/public_html/index.php on line 24
```

Comment: please how you deploy in command/text, not in video.

Comment: uploaded project zip in root directory, then uploaded the public folder in public_html and changes index.php

Comment: You geeting this error from your server, not from laravel.

Comment: Do you have any idea about what could be the problem or issues? I can't understand what should I do now.

Comment: show me `public_html/index.php` on line 24